# How to write query for date exact match in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, select, where-clause, str-to-date

I would like to know how to query to display the list

if date of user matches with the date `dob` in the table

user always have the dateformat as `02 Oct 1992` dd mm yyyy

How to convert the user date format(yyyy mm dd) and check the `dob`matches in mysql query

I have date in table as

userdate = 02 Oct 1992

```
user dob
xyz  1992-10-02
abc  1986-02-06

SELECT * FROM datetable WHERE DATE(str_to_date(userdate, '%Y-%m-%d')) = datetable.dob
```

currently the query not working

Comment: Please add sample data for both date columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for reply, above shown `dob` is date column and other is the datestring `userdate=02 Oct 1992`, i need to write query whether datecolumn and datestring is exact match, (for datestring i donknow how to convert to format yyyy-mm-dd and check with dob)

Comment: `str_to_date` needs in a pattern to convert **from**, not to convert **to**. rather than `date_format()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM datetable
WHERE dob = STR_TO_DATE(userdate, "%d %b %Y");
```

Example of date parsing for `userdate`:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("02 Oct 1992", "%d %b %Y") as date;
+------------+
| date       |
|------------|
| 1992-10-02 |
+------------+
1 row in set
Time: 0.005s
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: thanks but like the first query I want to do, but its not working, can help

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM datetable
WHERE dob = STR_TO_DATE(userdate, "%d %b %Y");` this query not working

Comment: You need to replace `userdate` with the date, for example `02 Oct 1992`